# Create zip archive based on number of files

Tags: solaris, zip, split

SunOS 5.8

Directory structure

/TEST/CHM

```
CHM
   A
     file1.txt
     file2.txt
   B
     file3.txt
   C
     file4.txt
     file5.txt
     file6.txt
```

If the parent directory CHM has less than 8 files/subdirectories zip it up normally.
If the parent directory CHM has 8 or more files/subdirectories create a zip archive for ever 5 files.
This is for testing only. In production it will be 10000 files, not 5.
Parent directory CHM could have 0 to n subdirectories.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

cd $subdir/

# vars
num=8  # set 10000 in production

for dir in $subdir
do
    dir=${dir%*/}

    # testing code only
          if [[ ${dir##*/} = "CHM" ]]
          then
                numfile=$(ls * | wc -l)
          fi

          if [ "$numfile" -lt "$num" ]
          then
               zip -r -6 ${dir##*/}.zip .
          else
               ls * > files
               split -l 5 - files < files
               for i in files[a-z][a-z]; do
                   zip -6 "$i.zip" -@ < "$i"
               done
          fi
    # end test
done
exit


   zip warning: name not matched: A:
   zip warning: name not matched: file1.txt
   zip warning: name not matched: file2.txt
   zip warning: name not matched: B:

zip error: Nothing to do! (filesaa.zip)
```

The else part of the second if statement is failing and I'm not sure why.
I'm looking to create:

```
CHM.zip master
CHM.001.zip
CHM.002.zip
CHM.003.zip
```

So I can unzip in the same order on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I followed your rules completely, but it might be easier to use standard utilities (and simplify the rules for what and when to create):

```bsh
find . -type f | split -d -a3 -l $num --filter='zip -@ $FILE.zip' - "$pfx".
```

`find` is rather obvious, tweak options to your liking. You might want to sort the list before passing its output to `split`.

`split`:

- `- d` - use numbering instead of alphabetical suffixes
- `-a3` - suffix length (the numbering) 3 places (digits in this case)
- `-l` - number of lines after which to increase counter
- `--filter=COMMAND` - pass lines to a command instead of writing into a file
- `COMMAND` - `$FILE` is interpreted by `split` as a filename it would normally use for writing, which means it has to be single-quoted (or backslashed to prevent interpretation by the shell executing the above command line)
- `-` - explicitly require parsing standard input
- `"$pfx".` your preferred prefix. The dot is intentional, `split` doesn't append it automatically.

Comment: I get an error:
find: path-list predicate-list
split: illegal option -- d

Comment: You may need a dot "." after the "find" command.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution that works on Sun Solaris. This will zip up 10000 files per each multipart zip and scp the master zip to the remote server.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
#------------------------------------------------------------
#-- Zip up content files based on $1 parameter
#------------------------------------------------------------
function zip_files {
   SRC="/ads/data02/CTS/Data/$1"
   #-- destination folder
   DST="/ads/acct/oracle/CTS"
   #-- amount of files that should go in each zip file
   FILES_PER_ZIP=10000

#-----------------------------------------------------------

  FILES="/tmp/multizip.$$"
  ZIP_PREFIX=$(basename $SRC)

#-- generate the list of the files to zip
  find $SRC > $FILES

#-- zip the files
  NUM=0
  ZIP_NUM=1
  printf -v ZIPFILE "$DST/$ZIP_PREFIX%03d" $ZIP_NUM
  while read -r line; do
    echo $line | sed -e 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs zip -6 $ZIPFILE
    ((NUM++))
    if [ $NUM -eq $FILES_PER_ZIP ]; then
       NUM=0
       ((ZIP_NUM++))
       printf -v ZIPFILE "$ZIP_PREFIX%03d" $ZIP_NUM
    fi
done < $FILES

#-- generate master zip file
/usr/bin/ls $DST/${ZIP_PREFIX}*.zip | xargs zip $DST/$ZIP_PREFIX

#-- perform cleanup

   function finish {
     /usr/bin/rm $FILES
     /usr/bin/rm /ads/acct/oracle/CTS/${ZIP_PREFIX}[0-9][0-9][0-9].zip
   }

   trap finish EXIT
}


#------------------------------------------------------------
#-- Main processing
#------------------------------------------------------------

for dir in /ads/data02/CTS/Data/*/
do
    d=$(basename $dir)
    zip_files $d
    scp "/ads/acct/oracle/CTS/${d}.zip" user1@10.10.20.25:/var/www/html/CTS/Content/A/TMP
    /usr/bin/rm -f "/ads/acct/oracle/CTS/${d}.zip"
done
exit
```